# Prestashop-Unknown column 'cl.id_shop' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, database, prestashop

After clearing the cache, my prestashop site presents this error:

> [PrestaShopDatabaseException] Unknown column 'cl.id_shop' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT cl.`meta_title`, cl.`link_rewrite`
        FROM `ps_cms_lang` cl
        INNER JOIN `ps_cms` c
        ON (cl.`id_cms` = c.`id_cms`)
        WHERE cl.`id_cms` = 1
        AND (c.`active` = 1 OR c.`id_cms` = 1)
        AND cl.`id_shop` = 1
        AND cl.`id_lang` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: May be your column name is different than you are using in query. Please share the table structure

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_cms_lang` ADD `id_shop` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 AFTER `id_lang`
```